# RcppEigen faster covariance

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have fit a regression model that outputs a covariance matrix, S, for the regression parameters B. I need to operate on this covariance matrix by multiplying by X, then get the new covariance and stderr vector

`cov(X * B) = X * cov(B) * X.transpose()`

Because I only need the diagonal of `cov(X * B)` I don't need to do the full matrix multiplications, I can just get the covariance of each row `X_i * B` and sum them

```
#include <RcppEigen.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]

using Eigen::Map;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::VectorXd;
using Eigen::SparseMatrix;
using Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace Eigen;

double foo(const Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix<double>& mm, 
           const Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix<double>& vcov) {

  int n = mm.rows();
  double out = 0;
  SparseMatrix<double> mm_t = mm.adjoint();

  SparseMatrix<double> var(1, 1);
  var.setZero();

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var = mm.row(i) * vcov * mm_t.col(i);
    out += var.coeff(0, 0);
  }

  return out;
}
```

For some reason this function is quite slow on 1M rows. I attempted to use "blocks" instead of operating on mm row by row, thinking the matrix multiplication with vcov could be made faster by operating on a block of values. This did not make the function faster. Here is a reproducible example

```
require(Matrix)

set.seed(100)
N = 2.5e5
p = 100

mm = rsparsematrix(N, p, .01)
vcov = rsparsematrix(p, p, .5)

system.time(foo(mm, vcov))
```

Is there a way to make this function faster?

Comment: Do you want to return the sum of the diagonal elements or the full vector?

Comment: The sum of the diagonal elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple mathematical "trick" that works if the covariance matrix is real and symmetric (and being a covariance matrix it is in your case).

The sum of the diagonal elements of `x %*% b %*% t(b) %*% t(x)` can be computed as

```
sum((x %*% b)^2)
```

which is super fast. Notice that the formula above above has `b %*% t(b)` as the "ham" part of the "sandwich" so you will need to compute the square root of `cov(B)` and then you can use the formula.

Alternatively, you can just use the following element-wise product directly in R

```
sum((mm %*% vcov) * mm)
```

I'm not that well versed with `RcppEigen` and the sparse matrices there so the following can probably be optimised but it seems pretty fast

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]                                                                                                                        
double foo2(const Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix<double>& mm,
           const Eigen::MappedSparseMatrix<double>& vcov) {

  double out = 0;
  SparseMatrix<double> mat;

  mat = mm.cwiseProduct(mm*vcov);


  for (int k=0; k<mat.outerSize(); ++k) {
    for (SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(mat,k); it; ++it)
      {
        out +=it.value();
      }
  }

  return out;
}
```

Here's a brief speed comparison

```
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(foo(mm, vcov), foo2(mm, vcov), sum((mm %*% vcov) * mm), times=2)
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq
           foo(mm, vcov) 32575.5488 32575.5488 33587.4147 33587.4147 34599.2806
          foo2(mm, vcov)   463.9440   463.9440   492.4232   492.4232   520.9023
 sum((mm %*% vcov) * mm)   953.7902   953.7902   981.4750   981.4750  1009.1598
        max neval cld
 34599.2806     2   b
   520.9023     2  a 
  1009.1598     2  a
```

Quite some improvement. Even just from using R alone.

Comment: This is a great solution! About 60x faster on my actual dataset